# AppleScript does not run from Automator

Tags: applescript, automator, macos-ventura

I try to implement a folder action with Automator.
So i use the module "folder action" and there defining the folder.
The only action module in there is "Execute AppleScript" with this code inside:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set fileName to name of (item 1 of input)
    display dialog fileName
end run
```

I simply want to know, if the file dropped into the folder will be transfered!

No dialog is showing up!

The workflow is connected to the folder, because when i insert an action module like "Delete file" it works!

Is there a permission problem?

---

I tried now the following (without Automator):

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
        display dialog (item 1 of these_items) as text
  end adding folder items to
```

This works fine and shows me that the binding to my folder works and these_items will be passed as a text to the dialog!

But this does not work!?:

```
    on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
    tell application "Finder"
        set fileName to name of (item 1 of input)
        display dialog fileName
    end tell
end adding folder items to
```

---

Strange: I tried with Automator again:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Finder"
        set fileName to name of (item 1 of input)
    end tell
    display dialog fileName
end run
```

and it WORKS!

What is the difference to the example directly with an AppleScript as above?

Ah, i made a mistake! it should be "these_items" not "input"!
Both versions work!
Thank you all!

Comment: What is `input`? If it's an array of `alias` specifiers you have to ask the `Finder` or `System Events` for the `name`

Comment: How would i do that?
Could you give me a code example!

Comment: Just wrap the `name` line in a `tell application "Finder"` block.

Comment: See my modification above! It does not work!?
No dialog shows up!

Comment: Sorry, I tried again within Automator and it works here! Thankl you"